# Remove title from hook_entity_view

Tags: entities

I need to remove title from rendered custom entity.

`unset($entity->title)` is not good because i still need to use its value in this rendered entity to use in markup.

css display:none is not good idea on my point of view as well.

Comment: "I need to remove title from rendered custom entity." ... "because i still need to use its value in this rendered entity" - you're contradicting yourself in a couple of sentences. Can you clarify the question.

Comment: for e.g. i need $entity->title to use in l() with some other url. Looks like it is not possible to do it in hook_entity_view and should be done in somevere else.

Comment: Where rendered title is generated firstly, in what function?

Comment: It was easy. I made it in my custom entity.tpl.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hook_entity_view()`, and `hook_entity_view_alter()` are not the hooks you should use to avoid an entity title is rendered, as the entity title is not generally passed to the `$build` parameter passed to those hooks.

This is the content of the `$build` parameter for three different entity Drupal defines.

- Node

  [image: screenshot]
- Comment

  [image: screenshot]
- Taxonomy term

  [image: screenshot]

Furthermore, the purpose of [hook_entity_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/7) is adding content to `$entity->content`, not altering `$entity`. The description given in the documentation page for the hook is the following:

> The module may add elements to `$entity->content` prior to rendering. The structure of `$entity->content` is a renderable array as expected by [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7).

To avoid the title is rendered for an entity, you should use a preprocess function for the template file used by the entity, and unset a variable used from the template file for the title. For example, for a node, a module could use the following code.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['title'] = '';
}
```

Similar code would work for comments, but in that case the function would be `mymodule_preprocess_comment()`.
For taxonomy terms, there isn't a title but there is the term name, which is printed from the template file using the following code.

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php print $term_url; ?>"><?php print $term_name; ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Setting `$term_url`, and `$term_name` to an empty string would cause the following HTML output to be printed.

```
<h2><a href=""></a></h2>
```

Comment: Thx for a lot of details, i solved my problem by coping default entity.tpl.php and commented out 'title'.

Answer (score 0):

By the comments it looks like you took care of this, but I was going to suggest using the [hide()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7) function in a template file and then print out that title variable where ever you needed it in the markup of the tpl.

Comment: Thx a lot, i did not know about this function.